# the distance between two kernels

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I wonder if there is some existing work discussing measuring the similarity between two kernels, is there any distance defined between two kernels?

A more specific question related to that is, considering for example two squared exponential kernels with automatic relevance determination:

\begin{equation}
k_m(x,x')=\sigma_{m}^2\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{q}\left(\frac{x_j-x'_{j}}{l_{mj}}\right)^2\right)
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
k_n(x,x')=\sigma_{n}^2\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{q}\left(\frac{x_j-x'_{j}}{l_{nj}}\right)^2\right)
\end{equation}
Can we have some relationship between the distance of two kernels (if have) and the Euclidean distance between two vectors of parameters of those kernels, something like ($A$ is some constant):
\begin{equation}
D(k_{m},k_{n})\leq A d(\{\sigma_{m},l_{m1},\dots l_{mq}\},\{\sigma_{n},l_{n1},\dots l_{nq}\})
\end{equation}

Besides, since Reproducing kernel Hilbert space is also highly related to the kernel function, I am also curious about whether there is some distance between two RKHS and whether this distance has some relationship with the distance between two corresponding kernels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clarify exactly what you would like to achieve with such a distance to get good answers. The reason is that distances come a dime a dozen. Here are just three broad approaches:

1. Metrics on functions
   Since a kernel is just a function from pairs of input spaces to the real numbers you can use any applicable metric on functions.
2. Metrics on positive definite matrices
   There are a bunch of metrics, norms etc. on the space of n-by-n matrices in general and positive definite matrices in particular.
3. Metrics on parameterized kernels
   When you focus on families of kernels which are parameterized by hyper-parameters you can apply any metric on the space of parameters to the kernels.